# Customization of Spring module versions while using Spring Roo

Tags: spring, spring-roo

I am new to Spring Roo. I am using Spring Roo of version 1.2.5. I am noticing that the generated pom.xml in new spring roo project is picking Spring 3.2.6. But the latest Spring GA is 4.0.2.
So, how I can configure roo to pick Spring 4.0.2 instead of 3.2.6 by default?

I tried to modify the version in generated pom.xml manually. But then I am noticing that roo is picking up older version of spring webflow instead of latest one when I tried to set up the spring web flow for the new roo project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible with Roo. Roo just gives you a way to start off. You can edit your pom.xml when ever you want after setup. There's no harm in doing that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way, future Roo releases will generate Spring 4 projects.